# Trying to delete all the elements from HashTable with the status marked as closed

Tags: c, data-structures, hashtable

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


enum Stare {DESCHIS=10, LUCRU=20, DUPLICAT=30, REZOLVAT=40, INCHIS=50};
struct Task
{

    char *idTask;
    char *data;
    char *numeInginer;
    int nivelComplexitate;
    Stare stare;
};

struct List
{
    Task *task;
    List*next;
};

struct HashTable
{
    List** vector;
    int size;

};

List* creareNodLista(Task *task)
{
    List*nod = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
    nod->task = task;
    nod->next = NULL;
    return nod;
}

void initHashTable(HashTable &hTable, int size)
{
    hTable.vector = (List**)malloc(sizeof(List*)*size);
    hTable.size = size;
    memset(hTable.vector, 0, sizeof(List*)*size);
}

int fhash(char c, int l)
{
    return c%l;
}

void inserareNodLista(List*&list, List*nod)
{
    nod->next = list;
    list = nod;
}

void inserareNodHashTable(HashTable hTable, List*nod)
{   //determinarea pozitiei pe care se face inserarea
    int index = fhash(nod->task->numeInginer[0],hTable.size);
    //obtinerea listei in care se face inserarea
    List*list = hTable.vector[index];
    //inserare element nou in lista
    inserareNodLista(list, nod);
    //actualizare element in hashTable
    hTable.vector[index] = list;

}

List* getHashTable(HashTable ht, char cheie)
{
    int f = fhash(cheie, ht.size);
    return ht.vector[f];
}

void printHashTable(HashTable ht)
{
    for (char c = 'A'; c < 'Z'; c++)
    {
        List*lista = getHashTable(ht, c);
        int count = 0;
        while (lista)
        {   
            count++;
            printf("%d", count);
            printf("%s\n", lista->task->idTask);
            printf("%s\n", lista->task->data);
            printf("%s\n", lista->task->numeInginer);
            printf("%d\n", lista->task->nivelComplexitate);
            printf("%d\n", lista->task->stare);
            lista = lista->next;
        }
        if (count>1)
            printf("\nColiziune\n\n");
    }
}

int stergeNodHashTable(HashTable hTable, char*numeInginer)
{
    int pozitie = 0;
    pozitie = fhash(numeInginer[0], hTable.size);
    if (hTable.vector[pozitie] == NULL)
        return -1;
    else
    {
        if (strcmp(hTable.vector[pozitie]->task->numeInginer, numeInginer) == 0)
        {
            if (hTable.vector[pozitie]->next == NULL)
            {
                free(hTable.vector[pozitie]->task->idTask);
                free(hTable.vector[pozitie]->task->data);
                free(hTable.vector[pozitie]->task->numeInginer);
                free(hTable.vector[pozitie]->task);
                free(hTable.vector[pozitie]);
                hTable.vector[pozitie] = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                List*lista = hTable.vector[pozitie];
                hTable.vector[pozitie] = lista->next;
                free(lista->task->idTask);
                free(lista->task->data);
                free(lista->task->numeInginer);
                free(lista->task);
                free(lista);
                lista->next = NULL;
                lista = NULL;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            List*tmp = hTable.vector[pozitie];
            while (tmp->next != NULL && strcmp(tmp->next->task->numeInginer, numeInginer) != 0)
                tmp = tmp->next;
            List*list = tmp->next;
            if (list->next == NULL)
            {
                free(list->task->idTask);
                free(list->task->numeInginer);
                free(list->task->data);
                free(list->task);
                free(list);
                tmp->next = NULL;
                list = NULL;

            }
            else
            {
                List*tmp = list;
                list = list->next;
                free(tmp->task->idTask);
                free(tmp->task->data);
                free(tmp->task->numeInginer);
                free(tmp->task);
                free(tmp);
                tmp->next = NULL;
                tmp = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    return pozitie;

}


void main()
{
    FILE *pFile = fopen("Text.txt", "r");
    Task *task = NULL;
    HashTable ht;
    initHashTable(ht, 29);
    if (pFile)
    {
        while (!feof(pFile))
        {
            task = (Task*)malloc(sizeof(Task));
            char id[50];
            fscanf(pFile, "%s", &id);
            task->idTask = (char*)malloc(strlen(id) + 1);
            strcpy(task->idTask, id);
            char data[50];
            fscanf(pFile, "%s", data);
            task->data = (char*)malloc(strlen(data) + 1);
            strcpy(task->data, data);
            char numeInfiner[50];
            fscanf(pFile, "%s", numeInfiner);
            task->numeInginer = (char*)malloc(strlen(numeInfiner) + 1);
            strcpy(task->numeInginer, numeInfiner);
            fscanf(pFile, "%d", &task->nivelComplexitate);
            fscanf(pFile, "%d", &task->stare);
            //creare element lista
            List*nod = creareNodLista(task);
            //inserare element in hashTable
            inserareNodHashTable(ht, nod);

        }
        fclose(pFile);
        for (char c = 'A'; c < 'Z'; c++)
        {
            List *lista = getHashTable(ht, c);

                while (lista)
                {
                    if (lista->task->stare == 50)

                        stergeNodHashTable(ht, lista->task->numeInginer);


                }


        }
        printHashTable(ht);
    }

}
```

I am trying to delete from hashTable all the elements with status marked as closed. The delete function is working fine but when i call it for al the hashtable, it got me error: lista->task was 0xDDDDDD. I cant understand why. Please help me!

[image]

Comment: Did you try using a debugger?

Comment: @NickZuber Yes, i did, and i see that after deleting memory list remains with 0xdddd and that;s why i am getting error. I mean that block of free functions in stergeNodHashTable function

Comment: @NickZuber I want to say that my list is not going null, after free even if i put it null(hash.vector[pozitie]=NULL)

Comment: `void main` is wrong. `while (!feof(...))` is wrong.